# Rails - How to ensure a parameter is updated correctly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events app using rails. For the payment process I'm using Stripe and some javascript to update the amounts. I want the user to be able to specify the number of spaces (quantity) they wish to pay for and for this to update the total amount they then need to pay. 
The code I'm using is updating the text for the total amount payable but it's not updating the server so every time I do a test payment only one single amount is collected. So, if an event costs £10 per space and I try and input, say, 4 spaces (£40) when I do a test only £10 has been collected by Stripe. 
I need to ensure the quantity parameter is being passed correctly.

This is my booking page code -

**new.booking.html.erb**

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>



                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>

                 <div class="calculate-total">
                              <p>
                                  Confirm number of spaces you wish to book here:
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="1"  min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces">
                              </p>
                                <p>
                                    Total Amount
                                    £<span class="total" data-unit-cost="<%= @event.price %>">0</span>
                                </p>
                          </div>



                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.calculate-total input').on('keyup change', calculateBookingPrice);

function calculateBookingPrice() {
  var unitCost = parseFloat($('.calculate-total .total').data('unit-cost')),
      numSpaces = parseInt($('.calculate-total .num-spaces').val()),
      total = (numSpaces * unitCost).toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(total)) {
    total = 0;
  }

  $('.calculate-total span.total').text(total);


}

  $(document).ready(calculateBookingPrice)

</script>
```

This is my controller code with the quantity param -

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
    def new
    # booking form
    # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
    # which person is booking the event?
    @booking.user = current_user
    #@total_amount = @event.price * @booking.quantity


end

def create

    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

        if 
            @booking.reserve
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end
end
```

**booking.rb**

```
   class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :quantity, :total_amount, presence: true


    def reserve
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        self.valid?

        # We can always set this, even for free events because their price will be 0.
        #self.total_amount = booking.quantity * event.price

                # Free events don't need to do anything special
                if event.is_free?
                save!

                # Paid events should charge the customer's card
                else

                    begin
                        self.total_amount = event.price * self.quantity
                        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                            amount: total_amount * 100,
                            currency: "gbp",
                            source: stripe_token, 
                            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
                        save!
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                    errors.add(:base, e.message)
                    false
                end
            end 

    end
end
```

How do I amend this so the total amount is correctly collected?

This is the output from my development log -

```
   Started POST "/events/25/bookings" for ::1 at 2016-10-06 18:57:42 +0100
Processing by BookingsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qHYjvqAqNORnpBKjk4KdQ4++X53Av1KVO+BVIWkq0asLbyd8ssEJKFFcvR9CQHwc+UdAM041gpO3ZFlz0t7o9Q==", "quantity"=>"2", "booking"=>{"stripe_token"=>"tok_191g7l2hHbuHRh0YjftQP0eC"}, "event_id"=>"25"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[35mEvent Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "bookings" ("stripe_token", "event_id", "user_id", "total_amount", "stripe_charge_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["stripe_token", "tok_191g7l2hHbuHRh0YjftQP0eC"], ["event_id", 25], ["user_id", 2], ["total_amount", 1], ["stripe_charge_id", "ch_191g7m2hHbuHRh0YGAZhmxIu"], ["created_at", "2016-10-06 17:57:43.430265"], ["updated_at", "2016-10-06 17:57:43.430265"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think name parameter is missing in the input tag. Try the below one.

```
<input type="number" name="booking[quantity]" placeholder="1" min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces”>
```

And check whether the quantity parameter is received with the correct value in server.

May be with  `puts params[:quantity]` in create method in the controller.

Comment: It isn't, I need to know how to correctly pass it using this process.

Comment: To pass parameters from HTML to rails server, setting the name parameter is the correct way. Or are you asking some other thing?

Comment: That's all I need to do? I don't need to adjust anything in the javascript?

Comment: Let me know the result of "puts params" - Add it in the first line of your create method. I hope you had a method named reserve in your booking model. If possible let me know the actual code of reserve method in your booking model.

Comment: I've edited the question above to include the booking model including the reserve method and I've included the output from my development log following the inclusion of puts params.

Comment: Can you check whether your booking_params contains params.require(:booking).permit(:quantity) or params.permit(:quantity) only? If you added the require(:booking) then the the input tag name parameter should be like this “<input type="number" name=“booking[quantity]” placeholder="1"  min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces”>”.

Comment: The last comment above - re the input tag has fixed this for me. If you update your answer above I'll mark it correctly.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Pls do up vote and mark it as correct :-)